# Vuejs: how to manipulate elements using webpack template?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-loader

I really don't know how to do this. And I swear I research a lot

[image]

this code return null

Comment: try to not use "-" in id use camelCase instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That element won't exist at that stage because it hasn't been mounted, it needs to be done inside the mounted hook:

```
<template>
  <canvas id="canvas-basic"></canvas>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
  export default{
    mounted(){
       console.log(document.getElementById('canvas-basic'));
    }
  }
</script>
```

See: see: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

And here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ksg7vyyq/

You could also use a [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref):

```
<template>
  <canvas ref="canvasBasic"></canvas>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
  export default{
    mounted(){
       console.log(this.$refs.canvasBasic);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gkc5c1ph/

Also, you appear to be writing code outside of the Vue object, make sure you look over the docs to understand how to correctly format your code.

Comment: Thanks @craig_h I just noticed it a few minutes after asking, but was not sure that the correct method was mounted, so thank you

Comment: No problem. `mounted` is the point when all the elements on the page exist, if you need to access them them to initilise the component then you should use the mounted hook. You can initialise data in the `created` hook. Honestly, you will rarely use the other webhooks, so those are the two to focus on learning.